# How do i reset to the default Camera setting(Unity3d)

Tags: camera, settings, unity-game-engine

You know when you first set up Unity it has that scene where a Area Light is acting kind of like a sun and the camera is a nice shade that allows you to clearly see around you?. I accidently changed my settings on my Main Camera and it has stayed there as a default like a solid color of blue.**How do I get the original camera settings back?**

**Feedback is appreciated in advanced *;)***

**Note: 
I set it to default as something else. I can open any of my Games or even make a new one and its still there**